# enabling/ disabling combobox when selected index is selected

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to enable comboxbox when specific country is selected, otherwise should be disabled.

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    cboCountry.Items.AddRange(File.ReadAllLines("..\..\TextFiles\countries.txt"))
    cboCounty.Items.AddRange(File.ReadAllLines("..\..\TextFiles\county.txt"))

End Sub

Private Sub cboCountry_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cboCountry.SelectedIndexChanged
    If cboCountry.SelectedIndex = cboCountry.Items.IndexOf("Ireland") Then

        cboCounty.Enabled = True

    Else
        cboCounty.Enabled = False

    End If
End Sub
```

When I select any country including "Ireland" combobox is disabled

Comment: Yeah... once it is disabled, how do you plan to select a different index? Certainly not with UI events (see comment above). And if it's via some mechanism of another control or code, you haven't provided it. It's kind of vague.

Comment: What I was trying to do is only enable this combobox if "Ireland" is selected otherwise it must be disabled.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try

```vb
Private Sub cboCountry_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cboCountry.SelectedIndexChanged
    If not cboCountry.SelectedIndex = cboCountry.Items.IndexOf("Ireland") Then

        cboCounty.Enabled = True

    Else
        cboCounty.Enabled = False

    End If
End Sub
```

'Or just convert the output to string instead of selected index and compare it

```
Private Sub cboCountry_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cboCountry.SelectedIndexChanged
    If not cboCountry.SelectedItem.ToString() == "Ireland" Then

        cboCounty.Enabled = True

    Else
        cboCounty.Enabled = False

    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
If cboCountry.Text = "Ireland" Then
   cboCounty.Enabled = True
Else
   cboCounty.Enabled = False
End If
```

since you're wanting this to happen when Ireland is selected, you should be able to just check that the text is set to Ireland

Case sensitivity applies here so makes sure Ireland is indeed displayed just as you're checking or force case for comparison.

Comment: Sorry for late reply, I have found out what was the issue. It was in the text file, for some unknown reason there were two tabs after "Ireland". Thank you all for your help and suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I literally tried the exact same code you posted and it worked for me. I created a Windows Form with two comboboxes, changed their names to cboCountry and cboCounty, changed their *dropdownstyle* to DropDownList, and disabled cboCounty.

```
Private Sub cboCountry_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cboCountry.SelectedIndexChanged
   If cboCountry.SelectedIndex = cboCountry.Items.IndexOf("Ireland") Then
      cboCounty.Enabled = True
   Else
      cboCounty.Enabled = False
   End If
End Sub
```

I also tried @Charles May's solution and that worked as well.